# Error when setting up continuous integration for Service Fabric Containers in Azure: The selected account doesn't have sufficient permissions

Tags: containers, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to get [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-host-app-in-a-container) tutorial working (Deploy a .NET application in a Windows container to Azure Service Fabric) but I am getting the error below:

**The selected account doesn't have sufficient permissions to access this team project.  You'll need to use a different account**

The tutorial asks me to right-click on Solution Explorer in Visual Studio, and **Configure Contnuous Delivery to Azure**  Unfortunately, Visual Studio 2017 v 15.5.6 comes up with the seemingly erroneous error above, with no further clues!  My account is the one and only administrator!  (Indeed, it is the account I used to create the whole of my VSTS setup!)

Any ideas greatly appreciated...

Comment: Did you get past this error? I have the same issue deploying an app service from VS 2017.